# Why Does ItemsControl Not Use My ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, itemscontrol, itemtemplate

I am able to use an ItemTemplate within an ItemsControl to render items in a specific format.  However, if one of the items within the ItemsControl happens to be, say, a TextBox, that TextBox is rendered rather than an instance of the ItemsTemplate.  From what I can tell, this is true for any FrameworkElement.  Is this intended behavior for an ItemsControl, or am I doing something incorrectly?

An example:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="5">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="20" Width="20" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.Items>
    <sys:Object />
    <TextBox />
    <sys:Object />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" />
  </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

I expected this to display four blue rectangles.  I thought that any time an ItemTemplate has been defined each item in the collection is rendered as an instance of the template.  However, in this case the following is rendered: a blue rectangle followed by a TextBox followed by a blue rectangle followed by a red rectangle.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is intended behavior, and is intended to allow developers the ability to add special one-time use controls.  For example, I might use this to add a Button to a ComboBox that clears the selection, or I might put a TextBox in a ListBox that filters the collection specified by ItemsSource.  I would love to hear that someone has some official answer for this behavior because I found it counter-intuitive to the use of an ItemTemplate.

Comment: It certainly qualifies as a yuckky conflation of the UI and the data model. Ew. But done, one assumes, as an optimization which hopes to mitigate `ItemsControl` busywork whereby it has to wrap each and every POCO instance it encounters. Especially since the `ScrollViewer` in the `ItemsPanel` can quickly implicate hundreds of thousands of these so-called "containers". It would be probably better this was a purely opt-in feature (i.e. if the base call to `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` simply always returned `false`)  rather than WPF barging in to assert the unexpected behavior you're reporting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` has a protected member `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` which is passed an object from the items collection and returns `true` if that object can be added directly to the items panel without a generated container (and thereby be templated).

The base implementation returns true for any object that derives from `UIElement`.

To get the behaviour you would expect you would need to inherit from `ItemsControl` and override this method and have it always return false.  Unfortunately thats not the end of the matter.  The default implementation of `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` still doesn't assign the `ItemTemplate` to the container if the item is a `UIElement` so you need to override this method as well:-

```
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return false;
    }


    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ((ContentPresenter)element).ContentTemplate = ItemTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: As of 2015, they might have fixed the second part. With WPF in .NET 4.5.1, if I return `false` for `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride,` then the template appears to be set on the item container.

Comment: I didn't need the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` override either in .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just speculating here, but I would bet that it's behavior that lives inside of the `ItemContainerGenerator`.  I'd bet that the `ItemContainerGenerator` looks at an item, and if it's a `UIElement` it says, "cool, the item container's been generated, I'll just return it" and if it's not, it says, "I'd better generate a container for this item.  Where's the `DataTemplate`?"

Comment: No, the logic is actually implemented in the `ItemsControl` itself, in its explicit interface implementation of `IGeneratorHost.GetContainerForItem(…)`, where it issues the `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` inquiry, and then either calls `GetContainerForItemOverride`—or casts the data item to `DependencyObject`. The latter is in fact the minimal requirement here, which begs the question why does the default behavior of `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` have a stricter requirement (namely, `UIElement`) than necessary? Maybe—as I alluded to above—to keep this WPF "feature" from kicking in even more.