# WPF Window.Show throws InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual

Tags: c#, wpf, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

In case this is relevant; I am using Caliburn.Micro and Castle.Windsor in my WPF application.

I have a LoginView with a LoginViewModel, which is launched on application startup without dramas. Then, once the user logs in, from within the LoginViewModel, I launch a SplashScreen, and the Main app view like so;

```
IoC.Get<IWindowManager>().ShowWindow(IoC.Get<SplashScreenViewModel>());

IoC.Get<IWindowManager>().ShowWindow(IoC.Get<MainViewModel>());
```

The first call works, the second throws an exception inside Caliburn.Micro where it calls;

```
Window.Show();
```

The `InvalidOperationException` message is: "Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual."

My understanding is that Window.Show() *puts* the Window at the root of the Visual Tree... also, more or less this same code is working fine in a prior revision of this codebase, but I've done some major refactoring in other areas, and now this has cropped up.

I'm guessing there's some fail in a related refactor around my use of Castle.Windsor or Caliburn.Micro but this error message is not helping me work out what that might be...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot determine exactly what was causing this exception, but I have resolved the issue by modifying my (very broad) ViewModel component registrations from;

```
Register(Classes.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .WithService.Self()
            .WithService.AllInterfaces()
            .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)));
```

To;

```
Register(Classes.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .WithService.Self()
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
            .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)));
```

Seems that using `AllInterfaces` was producing a complex and unneccessary dependency tree. There was no harm in this case in slimming down the dependencies somewhat by using `DefaultInterfaces` instead and that has resolved this exception, which I am speculating was related to a bad cyclic relationship between some View instances.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the "**Window must be the root of the tree**" error was caused by trying to bind the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox` to a collection of DependencyObjects which happened to have a `Window` instance at index zero.

When establishing a collection binding, WPF examines the contents of the bound collection to ascertain if it will need to use an 'item container' for each item--versus whether you intend the contents of the collection to be shown as native `UIElement`s (without a container). I believe this involves testing the first element in various ways.

This is a nice optimization in `WPF`: *don't generate item containers if the data can be displayed directly*. But if you do actually intend to treat the items in the collection as data (i.e. your app is a debugging aid or reflection tool), and if the data can contain a `Window,` then WPF's silent decision-making will get it wrong, because a `Window` can't be placed in the tree without an item container.

It's not just `Window` instances that can be a problem here. Perhaps more serious is that, if you were planning to insert those `UIElement`s from your collection in another visual tree later on, this would also fail, since UIElements can't be in more than one visual tree.

The solution is simple: Just specify an `ItemTemplate`, which will force WPF to use item containers.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="DependencyObject">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[edit:] The above code may not be enough of a solution. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844808/147511